# AvcaptureSession enabled during Splitscreen

Tags: ios, ipad, split-screen

How do i keep AVCaptureSession running during splitscreen, since AVCapture throws following notification AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonVideoDeviceNotAvailableWithMultipleForegroundApps when the app is opened in splitscreen and at that point avcapture session stops running.